# Linear Programming with a specific sequence in PulP (Python)

Tags: linear-programming

Would it be possible to implement events that occur in a specific order in a linear model? I would like to create a model where there are several activities in this order with a clear time constraint:

1. Intake - 60 minutes
2. Write intake transcript - 60 minutes
3. Create project proposal - 30 minutes
4. Discuss project proposal - 30 minutes
5. Discuss project results - 30 minutes

However, I only find linear programming examples with capacity constraints et cetera, but there is no information about creating a schedule where events need to take place in a specific order. Could you help me with writing such a model for **5 employees** that work with a schedule that is 6 weeks ahead?. Or could you provide me with a direction to look into?

Kind regards,

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are countless models with **precedence constraints**. Basically they all have the form:

```
   Completion time of job A <= Start time of job B
```

The exact formulation depends on the details. A continuous time model will be different than a model with time slots.